# convert XMLGregorianCalendar to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to assign a XMLGregorianCalendar date to a java.sql.Timestamp var, like this...

```
var1.setTimeStamp(Timestamp.valueOf(var2.getXMLGregorianCalendar().toString()))
```

But apparently, this is not working, and throws an exception...

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

And I've tried this, as well:

```
var1.setTimeStamp((Timestamp) var2.getXMLGregorianCalendar().getTime())
```

but...

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Any ideas..? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(var2.getXMLGregorianCalendar().toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
    var1.setTimeStamp(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Try to avoid legacy date-time classes. But if handed a `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`, convert to modern `java.time.Instant` class. No need to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    myXMLGregorianCalendar  // If forced to work with a `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` object rather than a modern java.time class…
    .toGregorianCalendar()  // …convert to a `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, and then…
    .toZonedDateTime()      // …convert to modern `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class.
    .toInstant()            // Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant` object.
)
```

Retrieving from a database, as of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) [4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) and later.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## java.time

FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

- [`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar()) is replaced by [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).
- [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is replaced by [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Note new conversions methods added to the old class.
- [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is replaced by `java.time.Instant`, both representing a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

Avoid using `XMLGregorianCalendar`. But if you must interface with old code not yet updated for *java.time* types, convert. As an intermediate step, convert to `GregorianCalendar` as seen in the code of your Question.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar gc = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar() ;
```

Now use the new convenient conversion method added to the old `GregorianCalendar` class, to get a modern `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

Adjust from that particular time zone to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object which is a moment always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from some time zone to UTC.
```

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. So no need to ever touch `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/206345)

Comment: @Machavity I had considered marking this Question and [the other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12712676/642706) by the same author as duplicates. But they are not duplicates. This one asks simply about going from `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `java.sql.Timestamp` classes .The other asks about a time zone discrepancy in that process. My [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227551/642706) gives additional advice about working with UTC to avoid such confusion. My other answer leaves out some details and comments, referring to this Answer for more info.