# My xmlGregorianCalendar coming with offset value ..how to adjust it? in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset, xmlgregoriancalendar

My xmlGregorianCalendar value coming as 2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00 .. I want to pass thisxmlGregorianCalendar value and get the output like 2020-10-02T07:07:38(which reduces 6 hours from the time) any suggestion on this please?

I have used this below method.

return new Timestamp(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),null,null).getTimeInMillis())..

But it removing the off set value but not adjusting the time. the output i am getting is 2020-10-02T13:07:38..But i am expecting the 2020-10-02T07:07:38 like this.

Comment: No, you don’t want that. -06:00 means that 6 hours *have already been subtracted* compared to UTC.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class and is confusing and long outdated. Instead with your SQL database use `OffsetDateTime` for SQL datatype `timestamp with time zone` or `LocalDateTime` with `timestamp` without time zone, Both classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert XMLGregorianCalendar to java.sql.Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508319/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-java-sql-timestamp). I recommend [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227474/5772882).

Comment: Also how are you determining that you are getting 2020-10-02T13:07:38? A `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn’t print in that format. (In my time zone I get `2020-10-02 15:07:38.0`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Your understanding of Zone-Offset is not correct

The date-time string, `2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00` tells us that the given date and time has been adjusted with an offset of -06:00 hours from `UTC` i.e. the corresponding date-time at `UTC` would be `2020-10-02T19:07:38Z` where `Z` specifies a Zone-Offset of `00:00` hours.

It means that if you are expecting a date-time of `2020-10-02T07:07:38`, you need to offset the given date-time further by `-06:00` hours i.e. it will be at a total of `-12:00` hours offset from `UTC`.

The following example illustrates this concept:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odtGiven = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00");
        System.out.println(odtGiven);

        // Date and time at Zone-Offset of 00:00 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtUTC = odtGiven.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUTC);

        // Date and time at Zone-Offset of -12:00 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtDerived = odtGiven.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-12:00"));
        System.out.println(odtDerived);

        // Get the date-time string in the format with Zone-Offset dropped
        String strDateTimeZoneOffsetDropped = odtDerived.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(strDateTimeZoneOffsetDropped);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00
2020-10-02T19:07:38Z
2020-10-02T07:07:38-12:00
2020-10-02T07:07:38
```

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException, ParseException {
        String givenDateTimeString = "2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00";
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(givenDateTimeString);
        System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar);

        // Derive the date-time string at Zone-Offset of UTC-12:00 hours
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-12:00"));
        Date date = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
        String derivedDateTimeString = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(derivedDateTimeString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00
2020-10-02T07:07:38
```

Comment: @TechSol - The date-time in `2020-10-01T17:41:00+01:00` is `+01:00` offset from GMT i.e. it will be `2020-10-01T16:41:00` at `GMT`. Similarly, `2020-10-02T12:53:50-05:00` will be `2020-10-02T17:53:50` at `GMT`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 2):

### JDBC 4.2 and java.time

Arvind Kumar Avinash has already nicely explained how the offset works (what `XMLGregorianCalendar` misleadingly calls a time zone). He has also already recommended java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I should like to elaborate on this recommendation. Assuming that you thought you wanted a `java.sql.Timestamp` for your SQL database, you should not want that. Since JDBC 4.2 and Hibernate 5 we can seamlessly transfer the types of java.time to our SQL databases. Which I recommend that you do instead.

### If using timestamp with time zone in SQL, use OffsetDateTime in UTC in Java

**If the datatype in SQL is `timestamp with time zone` (recommended for timestamps)**, transfer an `OffsetDateTime` from Java to it. To most database engines `timestamp with time zone` really means *timestamp in UTC*, so for clarity I prefer to pass an `OffsetDateTime` that is in UTC too. There are a couple of ways to convert, each with their pros and cons.

**1. Convert via GregorianCalendar**.

```
    // For demonstration build an XMLGregorianCalenadr equivalent to yours
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2020-10-02T13:07:38-06:00");
    
    // Convert to OffsetDateTime for your SQL database
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()
            .toZonedDateTime()
            .toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    // Show what we’ve got
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2020-10-02T19:07:38Z

Pro: it’s the official conversion.

Or **2. Convert via String**.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(xmlGregorianCalendar.toString())
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Pro: it’s short, and I don’t think it gives any surprises. Con: To me it feels like a waste to format into a string and parse back into a date-time object again.

**3. Convert via int**. You may convert by taking the individual fields out of the `XMLGregorianCalendar` and building an `OffsetDateTime` from them. It’s getting long-winded, handling fraction of second is a bit complicated, and there’s a risk of accidentally swapping fields, so I don’t recommend it.

**How to pass to SQL**. Here’s an example of transferring the `OffsetDateTime` to SQL.

```
    String sqlString = "insert into your_table(your_timestamp_column) values (?);";
    PreparedStatement ps = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    ps.setObject(1, dateTime);
    int rowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();
```

### If using timestamp without time zone in SQL, instead pass a LocalDateTime from Java

If the datatype in SQL is `timestamp` without time zone (not recommended for timestamps, but often seen), you need to pass a `LocalDateTime` from Java. Again there are a couple of ways to convert. I am showing just one:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()
            .toZonedDateTime()
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDateTime();
```

I am using the default time zone of the JVM in agreement with what the old-fashioned `Timestamp` class did, so the result is time zone dependent. In my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen) currently at UTC offset +02:00, the result is:

> 2020-10-02T21:07:38

### What went wrong in your code?

The three-arg `XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar​(TimeZone, Locale, XMLGregorianCalendar)` that you were using is designed to introduce bugs like the one you observed. It promises to construct a `GregorianCalendar` with the specified time zone (if one is given) and with the field values from the `XMLGregorianCalendar` (year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.). So the documentation says it quite clearly: if you specify a time zone that does not agree with the offset of the `XMLGregorianCalendar`, it gives you a different point in time than the one specified by the `XMLGregorianCalendar`. It might occasionally be useful if the `XMLGregorianCalendar` hadn’t got any offset and we knew which time zone was intended. But your `XMLGregorianCalendar` has got offset, so this method definitely is not what you want to use.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of the three-arg `XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar​(TimeZone, Locale, XMLGregorianCalendar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar-java.util.TimeZone-java.util.Locale-javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar-)